# What is a popular tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, terminology

I can see in the description of popular tags a little "flame". I presume this is for tags with lots of watchers and/or lots of questions.

**Question:** what are the criteria that a tag must satisfy in order to have that icon in its description?

[image: a tag tooltip with a flame glyph followed by '1.1m watchers']

Comment: A quick informal study suggests that it's 'anything with over 1k watchers'. I'm not seeing any counterexamples on https://stackoverflow.com/tags

Comment: It is shown if the tag is up for [burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) ...

Comment: @rene Can't tell if you're joking. `[JavaScript]` is up to be burned?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, yeah, we will feature that once the current burnination is complete.  But remember that we start to burninate only when the community agrees, so don't start removing tags already.

Comment: Oh no! Please burn the java tag before.

Comment: Wait, are you saying [tag:javascript] isn't the "close vote queue" I hear people mention all the time?

Comment: I kind of figured out that it was set against tags with over 1k+ watchers but is is the only requirement?

Comment: @rene you are either mean or a genius :) but I know where you are on the binary side of ppl regarding javascript

Comment: JavaScript is bae tho <3

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As [Undo suspected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378458/what-is-a-popular-tag#comment659845_378458), the number of watchers being over 1000 is the one and only requirement. Directly from the <s>horse's</s> source's mouth:

```
@if (Model.FavoriteCount > 1000)
{
    ...
    @Svg.Fire.With("va-text-top")
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

("favorite tag" is what a "watched tag" used to be called; the code still refers to it by the old name)

Comment: TIL Stack Overflow's code is written by horses

Comment: @TylerH The monkeys' hands were slightly better suited to the task, but their salary expectations got ridiculous.

Comment: @balpha Are the unicorns _ok_ with being called "horses"? There's some tricky politics to navigate.